# Why do HTTP/2 clients reject requests containing the connection header?

Tags: http, http2, burp

Peeping at the 'Working with HTTP/2 in Burp Suite' to find out why the option to strip the connection header exists, I found the reason to be 'This is because many HTTP/2 servers will reject requests containing this header.'.

Is there a specific reason for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the HTTP/2 specification states, in [section 8.1.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.2):

> HTTP/2 does not use the Connection header field to indicate
> connection-specific header fields; in this protocol, connection-
> specific metadata is conveyed by other means.  An endpoint MUST NOT
> generate an HTTP/2 message containing connection-specific header
> fields; any message containing connection-specific header fields MUST
> be treated as malformed

Having said that, many servers are more lenient and tolerate `Connection` headers to be present, although they are ignored.

The reason for this restriction is that the `Connection` header makes sense in an HTTP/1.1 request, where one request at a time was sent over a TCP connection.

In a multiplexed protocol like HTTP/2, it does not make sense for a request (a HTTP/2 stream) to carry connection headers, because there may be multiple requests on the same TCP connection.

As an extreme example, if you have an HTTP/2 stream with `Connection: close` and another, concurrent, HTTP/2 stream with `Connection: keep-alive` (although `keep-alive` is deprecated even in HTTP/1.1), what should an HTTP/2 implementation do? Close the connection as the first stream suggests, or keep it open as the second stream suggests?

Clearly this is not applicable to multiplexed protocols like HTTP/2, and that's why implementations reject such requests.